# Формировать ли запрос в MySQL поблочно или делать простыню?

Tags: php, mysql

Воюю с простыней, запросы в коде PHP 120-140 строк по 80-100 символов, т.е. по 14000 символов.
Запрос в БД (укороченный):

```
SELECT crd1.n AS r1, crd2.n AS r2, crd3.n AS r3, crd4.n AS r4  
FROM crd crd1, crd crd2, crd crd3, crd crd4  
WHERE crd2.n - crd1.n = ${size} AND crd4.n - crd3.n = ${size}
```

Это примерно 1/100 от всего запроса, т.е. по сути запрос в коде идет как простыня плюс еще несколько таких же запросов. Читаемость ужасная, время выполнения отличное))))
**Придумал временное решение** (только ради повышения читаемости) - если разбить запрос на одинаковые блоки (они там есть почти 60% одинаковых) и перед отправкой в базу просто соединять нужные, например (на самом деле блоки конечно гораздо длиннее, такие как в примере я и не думал бы разбивать)

```
$sql1="SELECT crd1.n AS r1, crd2.n AS r2, crd3.n AS r3, crd4.n AS r4 ",  
$sql2="FROM crd crd1, crd crd2, crd crd3, crd crd4 ",  
$sql3="WHERE condition "
```

и отсылаемый в базу

```
$sql=$sql1.$sql2.$sql3
```

**Вопрос 1**: сильно ли это увеличит время формирования перед отправкой в БД или все на грани погрешности?
**Вопрос 2**: заниматься ли оптимизацией типа выкинуть все операторы AS, порезать названия таблиц, алиасов и тд. или это грани погрешности?
*Спасибо за внимание, господа!*

Comment: Я бы по рукам бил за конкатенацию. Она только мешает чтению. Да и современные ІDE не распарсят такие запросы. PhpStorm например помимо подсветки синтаксиса еще и autocomplete для полей добавит если сконфигурирован в нем доступ к БД. Лучше форматируйте запросы, табуляция, переносы строк. Красивый длинный запрос лучше понять чем короткий но инлайновый. По-моему вы не тем занимаетесь. Ваше руководство в курсе чем вы заняты? Лучше создали бы класс, и каждый тип запроса вынесли в функцию, которая принимает параметры которые нужно прибайндить. Кстати я в примере заметил прямую вставку. SQLInjection?

Comment: не, эт не вставка)) это переменная, задаваемая в коде, по сути константа. если вызывается такой-то блок, то переменная равна тому-то, если вызывается другой кусок кода, то там свое значение переменной. так что инъекцией пока пахнет только в поликлиниках, грипп на носу... В курсе ли мое руководство?)) Секунду, сейчас к зеркалу подойду и надаю себе по мордасам!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значительного изменения времени выполнения скрипта от обоих вопросов Вы не заметите.

Подумайте еще о классе Query, который будет содержать массив полей, список таблиц и набор условий и формировать SQL запрос автоматически.

А еще запросы можно вынести в отдельный константный модуль

Comment: спасибо! а где почитать, что за константный модуль?

Comment: обычный php файл, который подключается через `require_once()` и содержит набор `define()`

Comment: ну то есть лучше разбить? читаемость и совместимость с другими программистами - повысится, скорость - не упадет...

Comment: я это дело впихиваю в сниппет ModX, как бы движок на меня косо не глянул из-за длинной простыни, вот и озадачился.